# How to wrap long line of values in CLion?

Tags: clion

Is it possible to wrap this long line of values into 1 line? I must hard code those values into code and it is very annoying to scroll this block over and over.
There are no newlines in this block.

[image: screen]

Answer (score 1):

I commonly use an escape character to break up lines like this.

```
int long_set[36] = [1,2,3,4 \
                    5,6,7,...]
```

The '\' character is used to break up the line.

Comment: But I would like not to break up lines, but have everything in one line instead

Comment: I am a bit confused, your question is "How to wrap long line of values in CLion?" but you want it in one line?

Comment: Next best option is to store the values in a separate header file to be brought in with an #include.